# I need to use a PHP tool to provide a series of checkboxes/dropdown inside flash, that upon player selection records to an xml

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3

Okay so this task needs to work like this:

1. Flash environment starts (as3 code base)
2. Flash receives data from xml
3. PHP tool inserts a dropdown menu of choices into flash environment.
4. Player selects from dropdown
5. PHP captures selections and writes to xml

So first of all, I dont want to do this another way, it has to be exactly like that. Now that having been said, i have accomplished the first two steps.  Here is the extremely basic xml i am working with:

```
< LISTING HELMET="1" TORSO="2" PANTS="1"/>
```

This stores 3 string id codes which flash loads up.  Inside of flash i load those three values and use them to index movieclips to their correct frame.  This is done.

So now i need to write a PHP tool that creates three dropboxes on the flash stage, each box should list red, blue and yellow.  When the player makes a selection in the dropbox the PHP tool needs to alter the three xml entries to record the player choice. Can you do this with PHP?  Or do the dropdown boxes HAVE to be in AS3 and the PHP just be about transferring the data only?

As a bonus, as the player makes his choices the PHP tool would update the variables in flash so the images change without rebooting the flash envronment.

Thanks for any help folks.

Comment: Given that its 2012, i think youve failed :-) Also you dont need PHP to create dropboxes do you - dont you want those in Flash UI elements?

Comment: I don't know who hired you to do this in this specific way, but I'd run away from a job like that as quickly as possible.  What a mess.  For starters, the data format is terrible.

Comment: It's more in the line of a challenge...  and that format is simple for a reason, i could of course layer it up and so forth but the process demonstration is whats important.

Comment: So can PHP create those boxes inside of flash?

Answer (score 0):

```
FLASH <-> DATAS <-> PHP
```

this is the only thing you should do between php and flash.

If you use flash , all the UI will be in flash , period , you should only fetch / send datas from php to flash and from flash to php. PHP should insert nothing into the UI , flash should ask for datas , and when they are loaded , render the ui according to the AS3 script you wrote. And when the user select something , flash will send back some datas to php.
You can look for **Zend AMF** , or **AMFPHP** if you want to use PHP classes directly in flash.

Comment: Okay, that matches a lot of what i am finding.  So based on that lets explore that option.

Comment: What classes can be used in flash to talk to PHP?

Comment: What would a PHP tool, that could listen and then write to xml, look like?

Comment: any php class when used <ith the AMF protocol.

Comment: a basic webservice. instead of outputing some html you can output an xml with php , then load the xml into flash.

Comment: Okay, i have finally found some good resources for creating xml with php.  So i need pointers on the communication between php and as3...